# Как дословно записать в textbox переменную, содержащую спецсимволы?

Tags: c#, строки, символы

Если выполнить такой код, то если в message были служебные символы, то в текст в текстбоксе будет отличаться от message.

```
for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++) { 
message += ToText(encrypt[i], ost); } 
textBox2.Text = message;
```

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, что значит дословное отображение? `Text` у `textBox3` - это уже строковая переменная.

Comment: Если бы на месте ```@"?+.eR???5\u001a?\u001b??s?\u0018?\u0012?\0O??}W?^?\u0013T??\u0011??\u001d?[\0(?+.eR?5\u001a?\u001b??s?\u0018?"``` стояла переменная - для примера ```string t = "?+.eR???5\u001a?\u001b??s?\u0018?\u0012?\0O??}W?^?\u0013T??\u0011??\u001d?[\0(?+.eR?5\u001a?\u001b??s?\u0018?"; textBox3.Text  = t;```

Comment: ```
string some_words = textbox3.Text
``` Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Ну точно так же поставьте собаку перед литералом.

Comment: Полагаю, у вас строка не задаётся литералом в коде, а получается как-то иначе. Покажите, как именно и откуда вы получаете данные.

Comment: Кстати, не нужно дублировать вопросы. Удалите один из двух.

Comment: Данные получаю так
```string message = "";
for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++)
                {
                    message += ToText(encrypt[i], ost);
                }
                textBox2.Text = message;

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию.

Comment: Что такое `encrypt`? Что такое `ToText`?

Comment: ToText преобразует biginteger в string, но это не важно - мне просто нужно узнать как сделать действие для переменной, аналогичное @ перед обычной строкой.

Comment: **Не пишите в комментариях!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужно, чтобы юникод-последовательности не превращались в символы.

```cs
textBox2.Text = message.Replace("\\", "\\u005C");
```

Еще посмотрите [`Regex.Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netcore-3.1), вдруг то что нужно.

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: Мне нужен такой же эффект, какой дает знак @ перед текстовым значением, только для переменной.

Comment: @Semafor отредактировал ответ. Если не поможет, значит ошибка за пределами показанного кода. `Regex.Escape` пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал и то, и то. С помощью отладки я могу посмотреть значение переменной message и сравнить с содержимым textbox3 - символы также съедаются

Comment: @Semafor [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string) еще всякие варианты. А так, нужен воспроизводимый пример, который не работает. Вероятно в строке не то, что вы видите в отладчике, нажмите кнопочку с лупой для просмотра в виде текста. С большой вероятностью в строке то, что вы видите в текстбоксе.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, изучу. В отладчике я вижу около 1000 символов, а в текстбоксе - около 10. Если включить визуализатор html или json - действительно показывает нечто похожее на текстбокс.

Comment: @Semafor ну значит в строке не то что вы видите в отладчике на быстром просмотре, а то что в визуализаторе. Следовательно, чтобы вам превратить строку в последовательностью юникода, нужно избирательно преобразовывать символы в escape-последовательноть, либо искать ошибку в коде, из которого вы эту строку получаете. Что содержит `message.Length`? Там точно должна быть реальная длина строки в символах.

Comment: @Semafor так в чем в итоге проблема то была? Я хоть в ответ внесу решение.

Comment: Я до сих пор не уверен, но думаю, что если попытаться записать в строку служебные символы (типа кода нажатия на кнопку escape) то вся строка ломается и ничего с этим сделать нельзя.